# How to display ACF relationship posts as a loop in a page template

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a new website which has ACF Pro and Bootstrap setup. I have tried various different types of code to display posts from a custom post type using a relationship custom field.

The below code currently display ALL posts within that custom post type and does not display the ones chosen in the custom field. For ease, both the custom post type and field name is called 'Vendors'

`````````````````````````````````````````````````
<div class="partners-container solution-container">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        Show posts below
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
      <?php 

query_posts('post_type=vendors');
$vendorposts = get_field('vendors');

if( $vendorposts ): ?><div class="row justify-content-md-center">
     <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'vendors' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?></a></div>

  <?php endwhile; ?> </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>       
    </div>
      </div>    

````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$vendorposts = get_field('vendors');

if( $vendorposts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $vendorposts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Documentations:

[ACF Relationship Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

[Function Reference/setup postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

Comment: Thanks, this works - not sure what was wrong with my above code but going back to basics with this one helped me and I can build on this code using Bootstrap and CSS.

Comment: It appears the problem was you did not have  "<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>" included